# Create weight node and edges lists from a normal dataframe in R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to use visNetwork to create a node diagram. However, my data is not in the correct format and I haven't been able to find any help on this on the internet.
My current data frame looks similar to this:

```
name        town        car        color        age        school
John        Bringham    Swift      Red          22         Brighton
Sarah       Bringham    Corolla    Red          33         Rustal
Beth        Burb        Swift      Blue         43         Brighton
Joe         Spring      Polo       Black        18         Riding
```

I'm wanting to change use this to create nodes and edges lists that can be used to create a vis network.
I know that the "nodes" list will be made from the unique values in the "name" column but I'm not sure how I would use the rest of the data to create the "edges" list?

I was thinking that it may be possible to group by each column and then read back the matches from this function but I am not sure how to implement this. The idea that I thought of is to weight the edges based on how many matches they detect in the various group by functions. I'm not sure how to actually implement this yet.

For example, Joe will not match with anyone because he shares no common columns with any of the others. John and Sarah will have a weight of 2 because they share two common columns.

Also open to solutions in python!

Answer (score 0):

One option is to compar row by row, in order to calculate the number of commun values.
For instance for John (first row) and Sarah (second row):

```
sum(df[1,] == df[2,]) 
# 2
```

Then you use the function `combn()` from library **utils** to know in advance the number of pair-combinaison you have to calculate:

```
nodes <- matrix(combn(df$name, 2), ncol = 2, byrow = T) %>% as.data.frame()
nodes$V1 <- as.character(nodes$V1)
nodes$V2 <- as.character(nodes$V2)
nodes$weight <- NA
(nodes)
#     V1    V2 weight
#1  John Sarah     NA
#2  John  Beth     NA
#3  John   Joe     NA
#4 Sarah  Beth     NA
#5 Sarah   Joe     NA
#6  Beth   Joe     NA
```

Finally a loop to calculate weight for each node.

```
for(n in 1:nrow(nodes)){

  name1 <- df[df$name == nodes$V1[n],]
  name2 <- df[df$name == nodes$V2[n],]
  nodes$weight[n] <- sum(name1 == name2)  

}

#     V1    V2 weight
#1  John Sarah      2
#2  John  Beth      2
#3  John   Joe      0
#4 Sarah  Beth      0
#5 Sarah   Joe      0
#6  Beth   Joe      0
```

I think `node` will be the kind of dataframe that you can use in the function `visNetwork()`.